# double horizontal line before modulus operator

Tags: javascript, modulus

I understand what modulus operator does. But what does the double lines do in "n-- % 2" ? This should be very simple but I am stuck.

```js
function padIt(str, n) {
  while (n > 0) {
    str = n-- % 2 ? '*' + str : str + '*';
  }
  return str;
}

document.write(padIt("a", 10));
```

Comment: its a decrement operator

Answer (score 2):

`n--` returns the value of n and then decrements it.

```
var result = n-- % 2;
```

is equivalent to

```
var result = n % 2;
n = n - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a operator similar to one you might be familiar with `++`. It's purpose is to decrement a value by one, after returning said value. If the minuses were written before the value, the decrementation would occur before the value is returned.

```
var a = 12;
console.log(--a); //=> 11
```

Versus:

```
var a = 12;
console.log(a--); //=> 12
// But if you use a below this code it's value will be 11.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something that is missing from the answers so far is that the code in OP's question is actually quite exquisite because it leverages the [order of operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) to **combine the decrement and the comparison into the same line**. Because this is a postfix decrement, the decrementing doesn't happen until after the modulus operator is evaluated.

Both of these would return the same value:

```
  n=10;
  n % 2; //0
---------------
  n=10;
  n-- % 2; //0
```

But making this a prefix decrement, or using parentheses to force the postfix decrementer to evaluate first would change the result:

```
  n=10;
  --n % 2;  // 1
---------------
  n=10;
  (n--) % 2; // 1
```

A more verbose way to rewrite the function in OP's question would be

```
function padIt(str, n) {
  while (n > 0) {
    str = n % 2 ? '*' + str : str + '*';
    n = n - 1;   //  This is the  decrementer fully written out 
  }
  return str;
}
```

No it doesn't significantly lengthen the code, but it does save an extra line. But more than that, it's just cool to find clever little tricks like this. Cheers to the author of this function!

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m5308Lat/1/) for a demonstration